# Move the camera so that all objects are in the camera's field of view

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

[select objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwLor.png)

[Camera is moved but top cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IaWk.png)
Move the camera so that all objects are in the camera's field of view

I want to make the objects that are not the selected ones invisible and enlarge them as much as I can while making all visible objects visible

```
Vector3 averagePos=Vector3.zero;
    for (int i = 0; i < set[num].Count; i++)
    {
        objectManager.SetActive(set[num][i], true);
        averagePos += objectManager.ReturnPos(set[num][i]);
    }
    averagePos /= set[num].Count;
```

if (move_On)
{

```
        angle += Time.deltaTime;
        if (angle > 0.01)
            angle = 0.009f;
        //   transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, destPos, ref velocity, smoothTime);
        Vector3 ve3=Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, destPos, angle);
        Debug.Log(Vector3.Distance(ve3, destPos));
        if (Vector3.Distance(ve3,destPos)>1)
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, destPos, angle);
    }
```

Comment: The highest and lowest position of objects x y z
To calculate, we need to smoothly move the camera to separate the camera's bottom left and top right coordinates and put them in that position.

And the position rotation of this camera is not fixed
I do not know
I'm trying to solve this problem

Comment: https://lopespm.github.io/libraries/games/2018/12/27/camera-multi-target.html                                  Is this useable this site example?  ... English is not easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    centerOfPos = new Vector3((maxPosX + minPosX) / 2, (maxPosY + minPosY) / 2, 0);
    Camera.main.transform.LookAt(centerOfPos);
    float hoizontalCamZ = (maxPosY + 1 - minPosY) / Mathf.Cos(Camera.main.fieldOfView / 2 * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float verticalCamZ = (maxPosX + 1 - minPosX) / Mathf.Cos
        (Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Tan(Camera.main.fieldOfView / 2 * Mathf.Deg2Rad)));


    if (hoizontalCamZ < verticalCamZ)
        camZ = verticalCamZ;
    else
        camZ = hoizontalCamZ;


    Vector3 newCamPos = new Vector3(0, 0, -camZ);
```